# Issue creating the backstage app using npx @backstage/create-app

Tags: backstage

I'm trying to create a backstage application using the following command
`npx @backstage/create-app`, but everytime I get the following error:

`@backstage/create-app requires Yarn v1, found '3.2.3'`

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I found the solution to this problem.
It seems that by default, backstage supports the yarn v1, and to fix the problem I had to run the following command:

`yarn set version 1.22.19`

I hope this help